# How can I load and submit a form via Ajax in Symfony 4

Tags: php, ajax, forms, symfony, entitymanager

I am loading a form via Ajax to my page:

```
$('.table tbody').on( 'click', '.edit-item', function (e) {
  var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
  e.preventDefault();
  var $link = $(e.currentTarget);
  $.ajax({
    method:'POST',
    data: {
      "id": id
    },
    url: $link.attr('href')
  }).done(function(data){
    $('.form-output').html(data.output);

    $('#form_save').on( 'click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var form = $(this).closest('form');
      var formData = form.serialize();
      alert("save button clicked");
      $.ajax({
        method:'POST',
        url:'{{ path('edit_form', { 'slug': page.slug }) }}',
        data: formData,
        success: function(data){

          alert("success");
        }
      });
    });

  });
});
```

Controller.php:

```
 /**
  * @Route("/pages/{slug}/edit", name="edit_form", methods={"POST", "GET"})
  */


  public function toggleArticleHeart($slug, Request $request){

    if($request->request->get('id')){

      $id = $request->request->get('id');
      $item = new User();

      $item= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->find($id);
      $form = $this->createFormBuilder($item)
      ->add('username', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
      ->add('email', EmailType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
      ->add('is_active', HiddenType::class)
      ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, array('type' => PasswordType::class,'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.','options' => array('attr' => array('class' => 'password-field')),'required' => false,'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Passwort', 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')),'second_options' => array('label' => 'Passwort wiederholen', 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')),))
      ->add('cancel', ButtonType::class, array('label' => 'Abbrechen','attr' => array('class' => 'cancel form-btn btn btn-default pull-right close_sidebar close_h')))
      ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Speichern','attr' => array('id' => 'submit-my-beautiful-form','class' => 'form-btn btn btn-info pull-right','style' => 'margin-right:5px')))
      ->getForm();
      $form->handleRequest($request);


      $response = new JsonResponse(
        array(
          'message' => 'Success',
          'output' => $this->renderView('form.html.twig',
          array(
            'entity' => $item,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
          ))), 200);

          return $response;

        } else {

          $data = $request->request->get('data');
          $entityManager->persist($data);
          $entityManager = $data->getDoctrine()->getManager();
          $entityManager->flush();
          $response = new Response();
          $response->send();
        }
     }
```

I get the message "save button clicked" but not the message "success".

And there is also an Ajax 500 Error:

> Uncaught PHP Exception ErrorException: "Notice: Undefined variable:
>   entityManager"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define and initialize $entityManger in your controller (i.e. `$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();`) before using it, change your controller as follows:

```
/**
* @Route("/pages/{slug}/edit", name="edit_form", methods={"POST", "GET"})
*/

public function toggleArticleHeart($slug, Request $request){

   if($request->request->get('id')){

     $id = $request->request->get('id');
     $item = new User();

     $item= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->find($id);
     $form = $this->createFormBuilder($item)
     ->add('username', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
     ->add('email', EmailType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
     ->add('is_active', HiddenType::class)
     ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, array('type' => PasswordType::class,'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.','options' => array('attr' => array('class' => 'password-field')),'required' => false,'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Passwort', 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')),'second_options' => array('label' => 'Passwort wiederholen', 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')),))
     ->add('cancel', ButtonType::class, array('label' => 'Abbrechen','attr' => array('class' => 'cancel form-btn btn btn-default pull-right close_sidebar close_h')))
     ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Speichern','attr' => array('id' => 'submit-my-beautiful-form','class' => 'form-btn btn btn-info pull-right','style' => 'margin-right:5px')))
     ->getForm();
     $form->handleRequest($request);

     $response = new JsonResponse(
     array(
         'message' => 'Success',
         'output' => $this->renderView('form.html.twig',
         array(
            'entity' => $item,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
         ))), 200);

      return $response;

    } else {

      $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $data = $request->request->get('data');
      // Create Entity object and set it property with setter and then do persist on entity object 
      $entityManager->persist($data);
      $entityManager->flush();
      $response = new Response();
      $response->send();
    }
 }
```

Comment: I tested your code but I get the error message: `EntityManager#persist() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object, NULL given.`

Comment: As per your code, you are trying to save data what you are getting in `data` key of GET parameter. Please check my updated answer, you need to create entity object which you want to persists and set its value with setters and then use entity object as argument in `persist` function. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tested your new update. Still the same error: `EntityManager#persist() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object, NULL given.`

Comment: probably the data is not in the correct format? `var formData = form.serialize();`

Comment: The problem occurs when persist $data. This is the output of $data:

Comment: Just a suggestion, put the form in it's own class and use `$form = $this->createForm(MyFormType::class, $myEntity);`. Makes the form reusable and tightens up your controller action.